# Legacy httpclient createClientConnectionManager() not called in proguard-enabled release variants

Tags: android, proguard, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-6.0-marshmallow

Working on a legacy codebase still stuck with the obsolete Apache HttpClient (getting rid of it is in the "after next release" roadmap). Using certificate pinning implemented by overriding `createClientConnectionManager()` in a class extending `DefaultHttpClient`:

```
public class CustomHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
    public CustomHttpClient() {
        // calling no-arg super ctor implicitly
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        // return ThreadSafeClientConnManager
        // using a SchemeRegistry for https port 443
        // with certificate-pinning SSLSocketFactory for https port 443
    }
```

This works fine on debug builds using `compileSdkVersion 23` and `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`. This works fine on both debug and release builds on smaller compile SDK versions without the legacy support library.

This does not work on release builds with `compileSdkVersion 23` and the legacy support library. `createClientConnectionManager()` is not called.

Proguard is enabled for release build with settings following SDK `proguard-android-optimize.txt` with the following added for the legacy support library:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```

Adding `-dontoptimize` did not have an effect.

Disabling proguard with `minifyEnabled false` makes the override to be called again. Disabling proguard is however not an option for me.

I know one workaround for this. Would be interested in learning the root cause and maybe better workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Worked around the issue by making the `createClientConnectionManager()` a static helper invoked from constructor, and passed to super constructor explicitly:

```
public class CustomHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
    public CustomHttpClient() {
        super(crateClientConnectionManager(), null);
    }

    private static ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        // return ThreadSafeClientConnManager
        // using a SchemeRegistry for https port 443
        // with certificate-pinning SSLSocketFactory for https port 443
    }
```

Now the custom connection manager is used in all configurations.